# Thumbnail rollover with text

Tags: html, css, image, rollover

I'm using the following CSS code to do a rollover effect with text:

```
.thumb {
    position:relative;
}

.thumb img:hover {
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity:0;
    opacity:0;
}

.thumb:hover {
    background:#f00;
}

.thumb span {
    z-index:-10;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}

.thumb:hover span {
    z-index:10;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="thumb">
    <a href="http://domain.com/"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Everything is working well except when I hover over the text: the rollover effect disappears and I can see the image again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is too much of styles for simple overlay effect, if you are interested to see a demo I've made from scratch than here you go

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6rKL/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" />
    <div class="overlay">Hello This Is So Simple</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;

}
```

Comment: I tried your code, adding an A tag to the IMG tag, and the link doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1991185 It won't as a div is overlayed, either you link the whole div like this http://jsfiddle.net/W6rKL/1/ or provide a button on overlay div like this http://jsfiddle.net/W6rKL/2/

Comment: @user1991185 Just realized, in this example http://jsfiddle.net/W6rKL/1/ please fix the closing div tag

Comment: @user1991185 It's upto you :) if it was helpful please mark this answer as correct